# I get a creepy popup periodically after installing MySQL

Tags: windows-7, mysql

I installed MySQL using the installer they provide for windows. After installing, I now get this weird popup window every few hours:

[image: image description]

Can someone explain what is it? Can I disable it? Or at least
 make it a background process without GUI window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Look in Windows Task Scheduler. On the left, open:
>
> Task Scheduler Library\MySQL\Installer
>
> Right-click in the ManifestUpdate entry and select "Disable".

Blatantly copied from https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,626478,626575#msg-626575

As per the comments, this appears to just check for updates as per https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installer/en/mysql-installer-catalog.html

Comment: Will that break something?

Comment: I don't think so @TomášZato - it appears to just be checking for updates - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installer/en/mysql-installer-catalog.html

Comment: @TomášZato, instead of disabling it, you could reduce the frequency of the checks for updates, if they occur more often than you want them to occur. You could do that through the Windows Task Scheduler. There's also a reference to a procedure for changing the time of the check at the link djsmiley2k provided, so you could change it to be at a time when it is less likely to be a distraction to you.

Comment: I believe (though I can't test) that the windows task scheduler will allow you to hide tasks too.